# Differenciate <img> with no "alt" and <img> with empty "alt" attribute with JSoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I have this method which tries to count the images that don't have any alt attribute (not even `alt=''`).

```
private int countImagesWithoutAlt(String page){
    int nbImages = 0;
    int nbImagesWithoutAlt = 0;
    try {
        Document dom = Jsoup.connect(page).get();
        Elements images = dom.getElementsByTag("img");
        nbImages = images.size();
        for (Element image : images) {
            if(image.attr("alt") == null){
                nbImagesWithoutAlt ++;
            }
        }
        return nbImagesWithoutAlt ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem on " + page + " : " + e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is, even if I have `<img src="blabla"/>`, the condition `image.attr("alt") == null` is false. How come? And how can I fix this code?

Thanks a lot.

*For the ones who want to know why I want to differenciate  with no "alt" and  with empty "alt" attribute. In my context (accessibility testing), it doesn't always matter if the "alt" attribute is empty. It may mean that the image is only decorative does not need a description. But, if there is no "alt" attribute at all, the screen reader is likely to say "image", which is not relevant for the one using it.*

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found a way to do it!

```
private String countImagesWithoutAlt(String page){
    try {
        Document dom = Jsoup.connect(page).get();
        Elements images = dom.getElementsByTag("img");
        int nbImages = images.size();
        Elements imagesWithoutAlt = dom.getElementsByTag("img").not("[alt]");
        int nBImagesWithoutAlt = imagesWithoutAlt.size();
        return page + "," + nbImages + "," + nBImagesWithoutAlt;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem on " + page + " : " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The interesting part is :

`Elements imagesWithoutAlt = dom.getElementsByTag("img").not("[alt]");`